How do I freeze only some embedding indices with tied embeddings?
I found in Is it possible to freeze only certain embedding weights in the embedding layer in pytorch? a nice way to freeze only some indices of an embedding layer.
However, while including it in a BERT model, I cannot find a way to tie those embeddings. Can anyone help me?
HF Transformers uses the copy of the embedding layer weights in the decoder matrix. However it is not possible to do it if my Embedding layer is a nn.Module instead of a nn.Embedding. Substituting the decoder layer with the custom module is not performing the weight transposition.

Probably slow, but may work good enough - after each step (or several steps) of optimizer update, just replace the weights you want to keep. Advantage is you can freeze any single weight you want (single value in a whole matrix if that matters to you)

Thank you @dankal444! Yeah if possible I would love to avoid workarounds that could slow down the training. I would prefer instead (if possible) to only define the architecture and use then some standard training loop

Not sure I would be much help then. However, I can suggest putting minimal reproducible example - just bare minimum of code to demonstrate what's your approach and what's the problem. It will help others help you

This is annoying to do because pytorch applies the gradient/update to the entire weight matrix. After calling backward but before calling step, you can manually zero the gradients for the embeddings you want to keep constant

It is not possible to do that directly: Pytorch handles gradient computation per tensor, so the whole tensor weights will either have their gradient computed or not. You basically have 3 solutions:

Make a custom Embedding module that has both frozen and non-frozen weights stored in two different matrices as suggested in the linked answer. This is way too complicated because you would also have to modify the decoder layer to use the changed data representation.

As dankal444's comment suggests, keep a copy of the embeddings you want to freeze, and after every optimization pass, reset them to the copy's value.

as Karl's comment suggests, do the backward pass as normal, but then zero-out the gradients for the embeddings you want to freeze. You could create a backwards hook for this, as follows:



#for example
embeddings_to_keep = torch.tensor([1, 4, 5], dtype=torch.int64, device=device)

def set_grads_to_zero_hook(grad):
   grad = grad.clone()
   grad[embeddings_to_keep] = 0.
   return grad

embedding_module.weight.register_hook(set_grads_to_zero_hook)



thank you very much @tbrugere! I implemented the third solution as you and @Karl suggested and I think I solved the problem. There's of course the overhead of computing gradients that we are not then applying, but as you said there is no easy solution for this problem
